# how to create a realtime countdown effect to the time left between a start and end time inside a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I have search the internet before asking this. But I never found any duplicate question nor answer in stackoverflow.

let's say I have a start time

```
5:00 AM
```

Then I have an end time

```
6:15 AM
```

given the start and end time above, how to make a countdown effect to the time remaining in between the start and end time. the out put I want is something like e.g

```
01:14:01
```

(that one above means, there's only 1 hour and 14 minutes left before the countdown hit the end time value) That output will be written to an inside one of the  of each row of data inside the table...the row of table is unlimited

e.g

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>blhblah</td>
    <td>THE OUTPUT GOES HERE</td>
    <td>start time</td>
    <td>end time</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>blhblah</td>
    <td>THE OUTPUT GOES HERE</td>
    <td>start time</td>
    <td>end time</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>blhblah</td>
    <td>THE OUTPUT GOES HERE</td>
    <td>start time</td>
    <td>end time</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

my code to get the start time and end time for each row is like this

```
$('td:nth-child(3)').each(function() {

    var start_time = $.trim($(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(7)').text());
    var end_time = $.trim($(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(8)').text());


     //THE OUTPUT COUNTDOWN SHOULD BE HERE
     $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(6)').text(OUTPUT HERE);
 });
```

Comment: But it's 3:15 PM where I am. How should that be handled?

Comment: If you click on the [tag:countdown] tag, you're taken to a list of questions with that tag. As of this writing there are 1906 questions about countdown timers. Adding [tag:javascript] to that narrows it to 845 questions about countdown timers in JavaScript. I find it hard to believe that you couldn't find a duplicate...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a countdown timer that starts on a specific date/time and counts down every hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494385/how-to-get-a-countdown-timer-that-starts-on-a-specific-date-time-and-counts-down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update VII**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

   let startTime = new Date()      //this line means doing timespan calculation with System Clock 
   let elems = $('#timerTable tr')
   
   elems.each(function(index) {
     if(index !==0)
     {
        let endTime = $(this).children().eq(3).text()
        //$(this).children().eq(2).text(getStartTimeHours(startTime))  //delete this line
        
        createCountDownTimer(startTime,endTime,$(this).children().eq(1))
     }
   });

   function getStartTimeHours(d){
       let ampm
       let cHours
       let cMinutes = d.getMinutes()

       if(d.getHours()>11)
       {
         cHours = d.getHours()-12
         ampm = "PM"
       }
       else
       {
         cHours = d.getHours()
         ampm = "AM"
       }
       
       return cHours+":"+cMinutes+" "+ampm
   }
   
   function createCountDownTimer(startTime, endTime, elem)
   {
      //let tempSt = startTime
      let tempEt = endTime
   
      //use current Date as token
   
      let tempDate = new Date()
      let cYear = tempDate.getFullYear()
      let cMonth = Number(tempDate.getMonth()+1)
      let cDate = tempDate.getDate()
   
      //use current Date as token
   
      console.log(cYear+"-"+cMonth+"-"+cDate)
   
      //let sT = new Date(cYear+"-"+cMonth+"-"+cDate+" "+tempSt);
      let sT = startTime
      let eT = new Date(cYear+"-"+cMonth+"-"+cDate+" "+tempEt);
      let timeSpan
   
   
      //***************************************************************************
      // This section is for the situation of date acrossing, if startTime later then endTime, then assume that endTime means hour in tomorrow and startTime means hour of today.
      // If you want this function, then replace this line :
      
         timeSpan = eT.getTime()-sT.getTime()    
      
      // with follow section:
      
      
      //if(eT.getTime()-sT.getTime()<0)
      //{
      //   let newET = new Date(cYear+"-"+cMonth+"-"+cDate+" "+tempEt);
      //   timeSpan = (newET.getTime()-sT.getTime())+1000*60*60*24  
      //}
      //else
      //{
      //   timeSpan = eT.getTime()-sT.getTime()
      //}
      
      //***************************************************************************
       
      
       
        let myVar = setInterval(countDownTimer, 1000);
        
      function countDownTimer(){
   
        
        timeSpan = timeSpan-1000
        let hours = Math.floor(timeSpan /(1000*60*60))
        let minutes = Math.floor((timeSpan % (1000*60*60)) / (1000*60))
        let seconds = Math.floor(((timeSpan % (1000*60*60)) % (1000*60)) / 1000)
        let countDownOutput = hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds
        
        if(timeSpan < 1000)   //if countdown equal 0 second, stop timer
        {
           elem.text("-")
           console.log("stop")
           clearInterval(myVar)
        }
        else
        {
           elem.text(countDownOutput)
        }    
      }
   } 
   
   
});
```

```css
td {
 width:150px;
 text-align:left
}

th {
 width:150px;
 text-align:left
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table id="timerTable">
     <tr>
       <th>FLIGHT (No.)</th><th>REMINDING TIME</th><th>ARRIVAL</th><th>DEPARTURE</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>CM 106</td><td></td><td>default time</td><td>7:30 PM</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>SL 6204</td><td></td><td>default time</td><td>5:30 PM</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>KL 552</td><td></td><td>default time</td><td>2:03 PM</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Update V**

If you wanna show  "-" when timer stop, then tune function `countDownTimer()`:

```
  function countDownTimer(){

     //if(timeSpan < 2000)   //if countdown equal 0 second, stop timer
     //{
     //   console.log("stop")
     //   clearInterval(myVar)
     //}
     timeSpan = timeSpan-1000
     let hours = Math.floor(timeSpan /(1000*60*60))
     let minutes = Math.floor((timeSpan % (1000*60*60)) / (1000*60))
     let seconds = ((timeSpan % (1000*60*60)) % (1000*60)) / 1000
     let countDownOutput = hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds
    //  $("#"+domID).text(countDownOutput)
    //if (isNaN(countDownOutput)) {
    //    elem.text('-');
    //} else {
    //    elem.text(countDownOutput);     
    //}
    if(timeSpan < 1000)   //if countdown equal 0 second, stop timer
    {
       elem.text('-');
       console.log("stop")
       clearInterval(myVar)
    }
    else
    {
      elem.text(countDownOutput);
    } 
   }
```

And beware parameters of function `createCountDownTimer(startTime, endTime, elem)`:

1. parameter `elem` should ref to only one Dom Element obj, not an array of Dom Element.
2. parameter `startTime` and `endTime` shoud be string, and must be like : "10:45 PM", "10:45:00 PM", "22:45:00", otherwise it would crash. Pattern like "9 April 2020 10:45:00 PM" is also wrong.

**Update IV**

It's close to solve this question.

Your code

```
$('td:nth-child(3)').each(function() {

    var start_time = $.trim($(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(7)').text());
    var end_time = $.trim($(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(8)').text());


    //THE OUTPUT COUNTDOWN SHOULD BE HERE
    //$(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(6)').text(OUTPUT HERE);
    // the line above shouldn't be called here, appending countdown output  should place inside setInterval.

    createCountDownTimer(start_time, end_time, $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(6)'))
    //No need to pass domID, but pass domElement
});
```

Then need to tune function to append to domElement, instead of domID:

`function createCountDownTimer(startTime, endTime, domID)`

alter to

`function createCountDownTimer(startTime, endTime, domElement)`

Then alter function countDownTimer() :

```
    function countDownTimer(){
    ....
    ....
    ....
       //$("#"+domID).text(countDownOutput)
       domElement.text(countDownOutput)
    }
```

Then it should work.

**Update III**

Append timer to table row, you could try code below:

**Update II**

answer question:

`1 March 2011` just a temp token, in order to create Date Obj, then use two Date objs (sT, eT) to calculate timeSpan. So, the date isn't matter, you could use any date at any month and any year as token.

If you wannna use current Date as token, then check the code below, I have updated.

**Update I**

You could use time form : "1:00 PM" or "1:00:01 PM" or "13:00" or "13:00:01" , all work fine.

Update1: if endTime is smaller then startTime, such as endTime: 6:00 AM startTime: 11:00 PM, then assume that endTime means tomorrow 6:00 AM and startTime as today 11:00 PM.

Update2: Add countdown timer stop function. When countdown equal 0 seconds, stop timer.

You could try codes below :

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

   let timeTableArray = [
      {  
         title:"Timer 1",
         start:"10:00 AM",
         end:"11:00 AM"
      },
      {
         title:"Timer 2",
         start:"9:00 PM",
         end:"1:00 AM"
      },
      {
         title:"Timer 3",
         start:"11:10:00 PM",
         end:"11:10:05 PM"
      }
   ]

   timeTableArray.forEach((timer,index)=>{
     $("#timerTable").append('<tr><td class="cell">'+timer.title+'</td><td class="cell"><span id="timer'+index+'"></span></td><td class="cell">'+timer.start+'</td><td class="cell">'+timer.end+'</td></tr>')
     
     createCountDownTimer(timer.start, timer.end, "timer"+index)
   
   })
   
   function createCountDownTimer(startTime, endTime, domID)
   {
   
      let tempSt = startTime
      let tempEt = endTime
   
      //use current Date as token
   
      let tempDate = new Date()
      let cYear = tempDate.getFullYear()
      let cMonth = Number(tempDate.getMonth()+1)
      let cDate = tempDate.getDate()
   
      //use current Date as token
   
      console.log(cYear+"-"+cMonth+"-"+cDate)
   
      let sT = new Date(cYear+"-"+cMonth+"-"+cDate+" "+tempSt);
      let eT = new Date(cYear+"-"+cMonth+"-"+cDate+" "+tempEt);
      let timeSpan
   
   
      if(eT.getTime()-sT.getTime()<0)
      {
         let newET = new Date(cYear+"-"+cMonth+"-"+cDate+" "+tempEt);
         timeSpan = (newET.getTime()-sT.getTime())+1000*60*60*24  
         //if startTime later then endTime, then assume that endTime means hour in tomorrow and startTime means hour of today.

      }
      else
      {
         timeSpan = eT.getTime()-sT.getTime()
      }
 
       
        let myVar = setInterval(countDownTimer, 1000);
        
      function countDownTimer(){
   
        if(timeSpan < 2000)   //if countdown equal 0 second, stop timer
        {
           console.log("stop")
           clearInterval(myVar)
        }
        timeSpan = timeSpan-1000
        let hours = Math.floor(timeSpan /(1000*60*60))
        let minutes = Math.floor((timeSpan % (1000*60*60)) / (1000*60))
        let seconds = ((timeSpan % (1000*60*60)) % (1000*60)) / 1000
        let countDownOutput = hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds
        $("#"+domID).text(countDownOutput)
      }
   } 
   
});
```

```css
.cell {
 width:150px

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table id="timerTable">
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211275/discussion-on-answer-by-kuo-hsuan-hsu-how-to-create-a-realtime-countdown-effect).